# HTML_purifier stripping display:none css from images, even with CSS.AllowTricky set to True?

Tags: html, css, htmlpurifier, stripping

That title is probably a bit confusing so let me elaborate.

I'm using HTML_purifier to clean up user input, although in this case the only user who will be using it will be myself (its in password protected folders). A long story short I would like to be able to add in image tag code to a web form, then on the page that it sends too use the code to display said image.

However i need the image tag to have css attributes added to it, one of which is

```
display:block
```

Anyway by default HTML_purifier removes this, detailed [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#CSS.AllowTricky) because of the CSS.allowTricky option. As i understand it if you set the CSS.allowTricky option to True, then it should allow

```
display:block
```

However after doing this its still removing it, just wondering if anybody has done this before as i can't find much documentation about it on the web? Its not generating any errors in syslog, so im assuming that its the correct implementation but isn't working as expected.

My code at the moment.

```
include('HTMLPurifier.standalone.php');
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('CSS.AllowTricky', true);
```

* UPDATE ****

The code should pass the config object (which the code already set) to the html purifier object. Putting it together it should look something like this.

```
include('HTMLPurifier.standalone.php');
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('CSS.AllowTricky', true);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,6724 (solution was passing the config object to the HTML Purifier object so that the config actually got applied.)

Comment: Exactly this, set the config up and never passed it to the HTML purifier object. Have edited question to include how the code should look.